# System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send a mailing list to 500 customer via Gmail for a client, the problem is it only sends 89 and then I get the following error:

> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: net_io_connectionclosed

The code I have does work when I send the 500 to local pickup.

I have read many post on this and the client says she has a limit of 2000 email per day, so I do not know what the problem is.

Can anyone give some insight into this.

Code

```
var emailMessage = new MailMessage();
                emailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailRecipicant,customerName.Trim()));
                emailMessage.From = new MailAddress(smtpEmail);
                emailMessage.Subject = $"{emailSubject}";
                emailMessage.Body = string.Format(body);
                emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;



                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    var credential = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = smtpUsername,
                        Password = smtpPassword
                    };
                    smtp.Credentials        = credential;
                    smtp.Host               = smtpHost;
                    smtp.Port               = Convert.ToInt32(smtpPort);
                    smtp.DeliveryMethod     = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    //smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
                    //smtp.PickupDirectoryLocation = "C:\\Users\\pht_000\\Desktop\\Customers\\Email\\PickUp\\";
                    smtp.EnableSsl          = false;
                    smtp.Send(emailMessage);
                }
```

The above void method is looped over via the following

```
foreach (var recipicant in model.ToList())
                    {
                        string emailRecipicant = recipicant.Email;
                        string emailSubject = recipicant.Subject;
                        string message1 = recipicant.Message;
                        string encryptedLink = recipicant.EncryptedEmail;
                        string customerName = recipicant.Contact;
                        SendEmail(emailRecipicant, emailSubject, message1, encryptedLink, customerName);

                        counter++;
                    }
```

Comment: What is the port number you declared?

Comment: Port number is 587